# Ошибка при установке Bitrix на Open Server

Tags: php, битрикс

Устанавливаю "Управление сайтом" и на 6 этапе "Установка модуля "Сайты 24" (файлы)" error

> Внимание! На данном шаге произошла ошибка установки продукта.
>   Повторите установку текущего шага. В случае повторения ошибки пропустите шаг.
>   [Bitrix\Main\DB\SqlQueryException] Mysql query error: (2006) MySQL server has gone away (400) SELECT * FROM b_cache_tag WHERE TAG = 'landing_blocks' D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:137 #0: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->queryInternal(string, array, NULL) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\connection.php:330 #1: Bitrix\Main\DB\Connection->query(string) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\lib\data\taggedcache.php:156 #2: Bitrix\Main\Data\TaggedCache->clearByTag(string) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\general\cache.php:487 #3: CCacheManager->ClearByTag(string) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\landing\install\index.php:472 #4: Landing->installFiles() D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\install\wizard\wizard.php:1 #5: CreateModulesStep->InstallModule(string, string) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\install\wizard\wizard.php:1 #6: CreateModulesStep->OnPostForm() D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\general\wizard.php:469 #7: CWizardBase->Display() D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\bitrix\modules\main\install\wizard\wizard.php:1 #8: include_once(string) D:\ASITES\bitrix.loc\index.php:22

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В процессе выполнения запроса сервер оборвал соединение. Проблема связана с настройкой MySQL и часто возникает когда на сервере установлен небольшой лимит времени на соединение.
Установите в bitrix/php_interface/after_connect.php:

```
$DB->Query("SET wait_timeout=28800");
```